# Show image in a table cell with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am using Javascript to create a dynamic table to show data I parse from a JSON object. I would like to also add an image in one of the cells of the table, and I would get the HTML code for that directly from the JSON object, like this:

```
jsonObject[0].Image = <img src="../img/img1.jpg"></img>
```

The problem is that if I just try to set the content of a td element to that Json element, it is treated as a string and not displayed as an image (Note: This approach was working when I directly showed results from a query I made to a database, but now I changed the implementation to echo the results as a JSON object), so I tried to create an img Element through javascript and set the source as the image I want to use, but nothing is shown, more than that it stops the entire table from showing.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Here my JS code:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); //New request object
oReq.onload = function() {
    console.log(this.responseText);
    var Json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var newTable = document.getElementById('Prodotti');

    //Create first row
    var tableRowFirst = document.createElement('tr');

    for (key in Json.prods[0]) {
        //create new heading
        var keys = document.createElement('th');

        // append Heading to table
        tableRowFirst.appendChild(keys);

        //set new heading text content to json information
        keys.textContent = key;
    };

    newTable.appendChild(tableRowFirst);
    var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
    newTable.appendChild(tableBody);

    for (i=0; i<Json.prods.length; i++){
        //Create rows
        var tableRow = document.createElement('tr');

        for (key in Json.prods[i]) {
                //create new heading
                var values = document.createElement('td');

                // append Heading to table
                tableRow.appendChild(values);

                //set new heading text content to json information
                values.textContent = Json.prods[i][key];

                if (key == "Immagine"){
                    values.setAttribute("id", "TD");
                    var img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.src = "../img/"+Json.prods[i].Nome+".jpg";
                    document.getElementById("TD").appendChild("img");
                }

        };

        tableBody.appendChild(tableRow);
    }
    };
oReq.open("get", "../php/getalltag.php", true);
oReq.send();
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("TD").appendChild(img);` instead of `appendChild("img")`

Comment: `document.getElementById("TD")` won't work as expected as there are multpile cells with `"TD"` as id. Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: Please use meaningful and consistent names for your variables/objects. What is `Json` or `jsonObject`, are they the same? Why not to use `values` (that's a bad name too) instead of `gEBI()` when appending the image (strings can't be appended directly though)?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. The problem was partly the "img" bit and partly the fact that I should've appended to values instead of getting back the object from the document, since this object still didn't exist in the document but gets appended to the DOM only later.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was creating the td element I wanted to append a child to, JavaScript couldn't find it by its ID. Having changed the line

```
document.getElementByID("TD").appendChild(img);
```

to

```
 values.appendChild(img);
```

everything worked. I'm guessing the problem was that this element still didn't exist in the document, so JavaScript wasn't able to find it. I found out about this by using the developer console in Chrome, so a tip for future me and future newbie developers: press F12 when testing a new webpage :)

Comment: Using the console/devtools should be in the first chapter of every "how do I become a web developer" book :)